# Induction logic, two conditions

Tags: induction

If we assume p(n) and q(n) are true and use this to prove that p(n+1) and q(n+1) are true is this valid logic?

Comment: Please specify your question. If you prove $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$, that is only the induction step of induction logic. You need to also prove a basic case. That is, you must also prove $P(1)$. Only then can you say $P(n)$ is true $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes: let $r(n)$ be the statement "$p(n)$ and $q(n)$". Now you can do induction as usual with respect to $n$ on the single statement $r(n)$.